# OAuth Not Working With Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, oauth

i am trying to connect my magento 2.0 store from my laravel application, when i make OAuth call from laravel to my magento 2.0 store laravel throws an error Class 'OAuth' not found.

OAuth is installed on my system and code works perfectly out side laravel but when i place code inside of a Laravel controller it throws the error

following is my code of OAuth call that i am making from laravel

```
$oAuth = new OAuth($integratoinData->auth_data->consumer_key, $integratoinData->auth_data->consumer_secret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
        $oAuth->setToken($integratoinData->auth_data->access_token, $integratoinData->auth_data->access_token_secret);

        $oAuth->fetch($integrationCredentials['url']);

        $responseInfo   = $oAuth->getLastResponseInfo();
```

please help me thank you in advance

Comment: Did You import the OAuth class?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '\' when making instance of OAuth:

```
$oAuth = new \OAuth($integrato...
```